# libvirt: Is it possible to get guest boot info when guest not responsible?

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virsh

Under KVM, I'm using `virsh create <guest.xml>` to create some guest, but sometimes, the guest can't login (may be various of reasons), is it possible to get the guest boot info outside by using `virsh`? For example, is it BIOS passed, or OS loading ok, or OS initializing?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct facility to determine guest OS status in the way you describe. If you bring up the graphic console via VNC, you can see if it got past the BIOS, and perhaps whether its startup process has finished, but not much more than that. You could configure a serial console and perhaps watch data printed to the serial port and try to figure out boot status from that.